# Is it possible that a website blocks .click()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook

I am designing a simple facebook poke bot, but i want it to
Only poke back to selected users.
This is my code:

```
var PokeTo = ["Mark Zen", "Kornel Zaminski"];
var interval = 1000; //1 second

var selector = "a:contains(";
var selector2 = ")";

if (window.location.href.indexOf("/pokes/") > -1) {
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        window.setInterval(function(){
            PokeTo.forEach(function(name)
            {
                if($(selector+name+selector2).length)
                {
                    var parentDiv = $(selector+name+selector2).first().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent();
                    var target = parentDiv.children().first().children().children().first();
                    target.click();
                }
            }); 
        }, interval);
    });
}
```

now the  elements seem to be found properly, but the .click() method seems to do nothing. 
I have noticed that facebook uses ajax, but does it block the .click request?
I have also noticed other people using .click() method without problems so I'm not sure why mine is not working.
Thanks for any help.
Also if this'd help, im using this script injector: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija

Answer (score 0):

By reading your code I dont really get it what is it you are trying to do there.

My answer would be to have a look at FB Javascript SDK for handling Facebook functionality.
[Facebook SDK for JavaScript with jQuery](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/howto/jquery/v2.9)

Comment: First, I visit facebook pokes page, then i search for a link with name of the user i want to poke. Then, through the parent-child relationship i get to the "Poke Back" button and try to press it

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be some error with the statement `target.click()`. Try using `$(target).click();`. That should work.

Comment: Sadly it does not help

Comment: Can you show the error that is being generated, if there is any ?

Comment: Did you try printing your variables using the 'console.log()'?
Try using console.log(target) and also, var target = $(parentDiv).children().first().children().children().first(); instead of var target = parentDiv.children().first().children().children().first();

Comment: printing console.log(target) returns the <a> element I want to find so i think it is fine

Comment: Try this:
$(target).on('click', '#yourid', function() { alert("hello"); });

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery `trigger` method instead of `click`.

```
target.trigger('click')
```

Make sure `target` is a jQuery object.